# jQuery Mobile Button Enable/Disable & TextArea auto reSize after change

Tags: button, textarea, jquery-mobile

- How to disable/enable a button? which is not in a form , in a navBar. I'v tried some examples , all fail.
- I'm changing my textarea text `$("textarea").val(x);` The text is changing , the problem it doesn't get auto re-size , I see the ugly scroll bar on the side  , If I manually resize it , its OK... is there a method to force refresh or something like that?

Thanks

**Update (TextArea):**

If i click on the text area and then press any key  -> it opens up as should be,
I'm trying to simulate it .. but fail , the binding is works , but the trigger for keypress/keydown doesn't , I tried some codes from googling, this should work , I think , mayb for nomral jQuery 1.6 , but not jQuery mobile.. My test are are on Chrome and iPhone 4

```
$('#textarea').bind('click', function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress", { keyCode: 64 });
    $(this).trigger( e );
});
```

Comment: This is really two separate questions

Comment: +1 as they are both good questions as well

Comment: also posting some code that you have tried would help out as well. I still think you should edit this question into one question and post a new question for the other part

Comment: it was code from google search , don't remember what

Comment: for the textarea issue : If i can simulate forcing : A) textarea focus B) key press down ,  it will solve the problem , how can i do it?

Comment: can you add the HTML code to your question as well?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Link button example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gRLYQ/6/
- http://jsfiddle.net/gRLYQ/7/ (Header button example)

JS

```
var clicked = false;

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if(clicked === false) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
        clicked = true;
        alert('Button is now disabled');
    } 
});

$('#enableButton').click(function() {
    $('#myButton').removeClass('ui-disabled');
    clicked = false; 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">Click button</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="enableButton">Enable button</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

> Links styled like buttons have all the same visual options as true
>   form-based buttons below, but there are a few important differences.
>   Link-based buttons aren't part of the button plugin and only just use
>   the underlying buttonMarkup plugin to generate the button styles so
>   the form button methods (enable, disable, refresh) aren't supported.
>   If you need to disable a link-based button (or any element), it's
>   possible to apply the disabled class ui-disabled yourself with
>   JavaScript to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, you can cause a textarea to autogrow by triggering a `keyup()` event on it.

Considering your original example code, the following works for me:

```
/*Note: I'm using 'on' instead of 'bind', because that's what I've actually tested 
with, but I'm pretty sure this will work with 'bind' as well*/
$('#textarea').on('click', function() {
    //First we'll add some text to #textarea
    $('#textarea').val('some dummy text to be added to the textarea');
    //Then we trigger keyup(), which causes the textarea to grow to fit the text
    $('#textarea').keyup();
});
```

Short and sweet version of the above, this time chained and with no comments:

```
$('#textarea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).val('some dummy text to be added to the textarea').keyup();
});
```

Adapted from [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-textarea-autogrow#14737000002377837).